# can I replace windows 8 lenovo intel wireless card with windows 7 toshiba intel wireless card?

Tags: wireless-card

so I have an old toshiba laptop (which used to be windows vista but I upgraded it to windows 7) and it is core2duo and the wireless card is intel(R) wireless wifi link 4965agn, which works really well.

I bought a new laptop recently which is made by lenovo, windows 8 touch screen, 8GB RAM and i7. However, the wireless card SUCKS. It can't connect to anything at all. The wireless card is intel centrino wireless-n 2230, and it also got horrible reviews.

What I'm wondering is, can i take apart the laptop and remove and swap the two wireless cards?

Comment: Only if the cards are not integrated solution.

Comment: Hm.. what do you mean by 'integrated solution'? How would I be able to tell if the cards are not integrated solution?

Comment: Unless you can wireless card from your laptop its an intergrated solution soldered onto your motherboard which cannot be replaced.

Comment: "Unless you can wireless card from your laptop"? Unless I can remove the wireless card from my laptop? Suppose I can remove the wireless cards from my laptop, does that mean I can properly swap the wireless cards? Is that the only requirement to be able to swap wireless cards? that they need to be able to be removed from the laptop?

Comment: I asked if these devices were intergrated solutions. I then explained what an intergrated solution is. If you can remove the devices then of course you can swap the devices but it won't solve your connection problem. All you have to do is supply the drivers for the device. I now for a fact the Intel wireless card is an intergrated solution soldered to your motherboard.

Comment: Yea I just didn't know what you meant when you say "Unless you can wireless card from your laptop".. but Hm okay so if intel wireless card is an integrated solution then does that mean there is no way for me to swap the wireless cards? So I am stuck with the wireless-n 2230?

Comment: Use an external wireless deveice with a dual-band wireless antenna.

Comment: Hm, okay so in order to fix the bad wireless card issue, im going to have to have an external wireless device plugged into my laptop whenever I want to use the wifi? No other work around? Is there a way to upgrade the wireless card or make it better?

Comment: Unless you have the technical and soldering skills to remove and install an intergerated wireless device from your working laptop and replace the (nonworking) wireless device in the other laptop the external device is the non-technical tooless effortless option.

Comment: Hm, okay and earlier when you said "All you have to do is supply the drivers for the device".. does that mean, after I remove and swap the wireless cards, I install the drivers from the intel website and I should be good?

Comment: What part of that statement don't you understand?

Comment: How do I 'supply the drivers for the device'? Do I just go to the intel website and install the drivers? Like, by using this link: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&ProdId=2753&DwnldID=22510&ProductFamily=Wireless+Networking&ProductLine=Intel%C2%AE+Wi-Fi+Products&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+Wireless+WiFi+Link+4965AGN&lang=eng ?

Comment: Locate the driver for the device you wish to install and install it( the driver).  Of course none of those devices on that page can be removed from the system they come with because they are integrated solutions

Comment: Okay perfect, thanks! i would thumbs up but I can't thumbs up anything for some reason (probably cause I'm new)